# Xcode 6 missing required Architecture in custom SDK build, how to include all archs properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture

I've got a framework file that I inherited and manage in Xcode6, as well as a demo application that uses the framework file.  I generally build the framework project, copy the created .framework file into said demo app, and compile that demo app.

Recently I'm running into problems where the framework is said not to have the required architectures, keeping my demo app from building.  I've been banging my head on trying to get the SDK to build with all architectures, but no matter what I do the demo app can't find what it needs.  It has run fine previously, but now doesn't.

What can I do to ensure this SDK gets built with any archs that could be needed by a consumer in Xcode?

Also see update below.  It appears the run script does most of the compiling, and I'm not sure if it uses the settings even?

The error in the demo app build:

```
missing required architecture x86_64 in file 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BeaconManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in StartViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The build settings on the SDK.  I've expanded the arch values to be as complete as possible, but it hasn't helped.  The .framework file has ballooned from 1mb to 8mb after adding all these too.

[image]

UPDATE:

There is a build script that appears to do more compiling on its own.  I haven't determined if this script determines the architecture on its own or if it still respects all the settings I've attempted to update in Xcode.  What I've learned is that the SDK does not work in simulators once built, but does work when the demo app+SDK is put on the actual Iphone device.

```
xcodebuild -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -target BeaconSDK -sdk iphoneos -SYMROOT=${SYMROOT} -OBJROOT=${OBJROOT}

xcodebuild -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -target BeaconSDK -sdk iphonesimulator -SYMROOT=${SYMROOT} -OBJROOT=${OBJROOT}

INSTALL_DIR=${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}
BUILD_DIR=${SRCROOT}/build

DEVICE_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${TARGET_NAME}
SIMULATOR_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET_NAME}

# Create and renews the final product folder.
rm -rf "${INSTALL_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/A/Headers"

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create ${SIMULATOR_DIR}/BeaconSDK ${DEVICE_DIR}/BeaconSDK -o ${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/A/BeaconSDK

# Copy the header files to the final product folder.
cp -r "${SIMULATOR_DIR}/Headers/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/A/Headers/"

mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/A/Resources"

cp -r "${DEVICE_DIR}/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/A/Resources/"

#create relative symbolic link.
cd ${INSTALL_DIR}

#link
ln -s A Versions/Current
ln -s Versions/A/BeaconSDK BeaconSDK
ln -s Versions/A/Resources Resources
ln -s Versions/A/Headers Headers
```

Comment: This framework file that you inherited -- is it only available in binary form, or did it come as source code?  If it's only available as binary, then it may have not been compiled with the right architectures for your app.  (If that is the case, and you cannot control that original binary, you might consider removing the offending architecture from the supported list)

Comment: I've got the sourcecode and XCode project for this framework; it is all internal at my company, but I didn't create it.  I require the x86_64 in this case to be able to run it in the XCode Simulator for Iphone6, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was completely broken when I went to bed after 7 hours debugging.  When I woke up it compiled normal without any architectural errors.  This isn't the first time XCode has failed to update the settings and then hours or a day later respected the changes.  I wonder if there was some sort of caching, retained values, etc going on.   I did not reboot or even close XCode overnight either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile the framework using the same architecture list as your project.  It needs to have a 64 bit slice in the framework in order to be linked to a 64 bit application.  Sounds like you just rebuild the framework with the latest compiler settings and you should be good to go.

Comment: The architecture settings don't seem to help here, even when made identical for fully filled out.  I found a Run Script that appears to be more relevant, included in the update above.